# Android, remove gravity from the accelerometer using the compass

Tags: android, math, physics

First of all, I suppose the device at rest at the first measure so the acceleration I have is the gravity one, second I won't use a low pass filter.

Android gives me the linear acceleration and the compass value. My guess is that I can use the compass to rotate the acceleration to the earth reference and so remove gravity.
My guess is that if I calculate the difference of two compass measurement I have a quantity that is index of the rotation of the cellphone and so, if I add it to the initial gravity vector i can rotate it too.

Then at the i-th measure I have, my guess is this:

```
#a[i] contains the 3-acceleration at time i
#b[i] cointains the 3-compass values at time i
b[i]=numpy.sin(b[i]/(180./math.pi)) # I normalize the compass values from 0 to 1
#since b is a unit vector I need to "de-normalize" it
b[i]=b[i]*sqrt(g**2.)
deltab=b[i]-b[i-1]
# At the very beginning of the code I had something like g=a[0]
g=g-deltab #well I've tried also with the plus sign
```

it don't work..but I can't see the problem..any idea?

EDIT: I'm also trying this method, which again I don't know why it don't works:
I've found here to compute the rotation matrix giving the vector and the rotation angle.
Here is how to build this matrix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle
The angle I've choosen is the one of the scalar product  by the old and the new compass direction.
The vector with which they rotate is the cross product between the old and the new vector (I guess..and this may be wrong)
So: If I get the rotation of the compass, and then I build the rotation matrix, and then I apply it to my initial gravity vector, is it the correct rotate the gravity vector?

```
#a[i] contains the 3-acceleration at time i
#b[i] cointains the 3-compass values at time i
omega=cross(b[i],b[i-1])
theta=dot(b[i],b[i-1])/sqrt(dot(b[i],b[i])*dot(b[i-1],b[i-1]))
M=rotationMatrix(omega,theta)
aWithoutGravity[i]=dot(M,a[i])
```

Comment: Please help us understand the question. If "the device at rest" then what you measure *is* the gravity. As for the rest of the question, I don't understand it. Please tell us what you would like to do. Not how you think it should be solved but your intentions.

Comment: If the user moves the phone, for e.g. rotating it, the phone will measure an acceleration in a different direction compared to the initial one, and I cannot discriminate the pure user acceleration from the gravitational one.

Comment: What's wrong with `Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY`? Sound like you want either that or the `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION`.

Comment: I fear it is computed with a low pass filter on the acceleration, and so smalls jerk will be taken into the gravitational components (e.g. try to only rotate the cellphone and you'll see that lineare accelerations appears). The accelerometer can't measure a rotation centered in the accelerometer itself, and so, the linear acceleration that I measure when I rotate the phone is due to the gravity badly cancelled in `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION`.

Comment: Nope, you don't have to fear that. It's properly done with sensor fusion and **definitely not** with a low pass filter; see [Sensor Fusion on Android Devices: A Revolution in Motion Processing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k).

Comment: But I don't have a compass in my cellphone so there is no way to do it, as @tom10 said in his reply.

Comment: Do you have gyros? If you do, you can do it reasonably well.

Comment: Oh sorry there is a typo in my last comment..I meant I don't have a gyro.

Comment: OK, but you have a compass, right? Would it be an acceptable solution if it worked only in cases where the phone is not accelerating? Because in that case you can do it. Won't work perfectly but it still more than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe it, **this problem can not be solved**.  If you had two coordinate systems, you could describe one in terms of the other, but you only have two vectors (described within coordinate system of the phone), and single vectors introduce ambiguities, since you really only know the angle between them.

For example, consider taking an initial measurement of the gravity and magnetic field vector and now rotate and spin your phone.  You can again measure the magnetic field vector, but imagine you don't know the gravity vector, where will it be?  All you know is its angle relative to the magnetic field vector (and you might also assume you know its magnitude), basically forming a cone around the magnetic field vector (or ring if you assume the magnitude).  But since you don't know exact information about it, you can't use it to completely determine the linear acceleration.  That is, given a measured acceleration (physically, gravity + linear acceleration), every vector in the cone of possible gravity vectors would imply a different linear acceleration.

It does get you part of the way there, in that you now have a complicated geometry problem where there will only be a certain range of linear acceleration vectors that will be consistent with the "gravity cone", but the problem become much more complicated than a simple subtraction, and there's no a priori reason to believe that this smaller subset of possible linear acceleration vectors tells you anything useful.

For example, consider that the original reading of the compass is `(1,0,0)`, and the reading for acceleration is `(6, 6, 0)`.  If the phone is then just rotated about `(1,0,0)`, other readings of acceleration are possible, such as  `(6, -6, 0)`, `(6, 0, 6)`, `(6, 0, -6)`, and many in between.  So, because of this ambiguity, one can't tell based purely on the compass reading whether `(6, 6, 0)` changed into, say, `(6, -6, 0)` because of the acceleration or because the phone was rotated.

Comment: But, I don't have only an angle..I have 3 components compass in different times. I also know I can build a Rotation Matrix from a vector and an angle: I guess the axis of the rotation is the cross product of the two compass direction at different time (which give me the axis perpendicular to the rotation) and the  rotation angle should be the dot between the two compass vector. If I apply this matrix to the initial gravitational vector, shouldn't I be able to correctly rotate the gravitational vector?

Comment: For any single compass reading, you can rotate your phone about the axis of the magnetic field vector and you'll get exactly the same reading.  Taking readings at different times does not remove this ambiguity; instead, you'll just have a bunch of ambiguous readings.  A single vector does not determine a coordinate system.

Comment: You're right!! It took me a bit to understand what was wrong in my idea! Thank you so much!! In fact If I suppose (for semplicity) that for the three compass I measure (1,0,0) and an acceleration (0,-9.8,0), then, If I make now a rotation on the 2nd and 3d axis the value measured by the compass is the same but the acceleration vector changes, so I cannot reconstruct the gravity vector from teh compass one.

Comment: Good.  I like your example too, so I'll add one into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The compass values (i.e. the values from the android sensor `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`) has components in both the gravity direction and the direction of magnetic north.  So you can use it, in conjunction with the gravity vector, to work out the direction of east, because that's given by the [vector cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the two vectors.  In fact, depending on where you are in the world, the `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` component in the gravity direction can be quite large.

Also note that Android has two sensors `Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY` and `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` which are derived from `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`.  And it's always true that the readings satisfy

```
Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER =  Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY + Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION
```

Comment: Oh! I now wonder how Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY is computed! is a low pass filter used? I don't like this kind of solution because it remove the slow acceleration components!

Comment: @user1833218 I know that from Android version 4.0 onwards, the gyroscope is part of the sensor fusion calculations for Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY, because if a device doesn't have a gyroscope then Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY is unavailable.  Apart from that, my understanding is that it uses Kalman filters rather than low pass filters.  So I'm sure that it's a very sophisticated algorithm :-).